# SAP GUI scripting - Button press fails

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am using a macro in an Excel file that runs the SAP GUI. There is a step where, when I click a button in SAP there will be another window that pops up.

For that I have written a code like this:

```
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/XX/btnXX").press
session.findbyid("wnd[1]/XX/btnXXX").press
```

There is a button (`btnXXX`) in the window (`wnd[1]`). But when I execute this query, I am getting an error object not found for `findbyid`.

When I keep the break point and execute it, it is throwing error on 2nd line in the above code. I try to pick the `activewindow.name` and it shows `wnd[0]` still. Here the issue is `wnd[1]` is not getting opened.

Does somebody know why the 2nd "button press" doesn't work?

Comment: Is that a non-SAPGUI popup? What generates the SAP GUI recorder? Can you explain what screens you work with/show them?

Comment: It's a SAP GUI popup. Recorder also generates the wnd[1]

Comment: Please add screen shots, it's essential. Currently I find it practically impossible to help. Moreover, could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and paste it here.

Comment: I have the same error.  Something as simple as the transaction bar not responding to pressing the check button but will work if I press enter.  Wondering if you were able to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace all mouse clicks with keyboard strokes.

Replace:

```
session.findbyid("wnd[0]/XX/btnXX").press
```

With:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(N)
```

Where N is the linked hot-key ID.

To get the exact command, use SAP script recording and only use the keyboard to transition between views and windows.  The easiest way to determine how is to hover your mouse over the buttons you would normally click to learn the hot-key then record the hot-key.

Note 1) So far I have found that btn[XX] always maps to sendVKey(XX), but I can't be certain this is always the case.

Note 2) sendVKey always appears to be referenced off the window (wnd[Y]) even if a button is another layer down (/tbar, /usr, etc.).